# mustache.js vs dust.js : how can i target my school array?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, mustache, dust.js

If you view my code at http://bucktowndigital.com/js_templates/mustache/v2-pub.html, you'll see that i'm having trouble with the High School and College arrays in the schools object.

i know mustache and dust are logic-less, but does this mean i can't use logic at all when utiilizing them?

for example, i want to put some conditional code that states that if there's 2 or more schools of type college, then only list the first item in the array.

Also, I will be doing this same test using dust.js.

Will I run into the same problem?

I don't necessarily need the right answer, but to pointed in the right direction for tackling the problem.

See json data: http://bucktowndigital.com/js_templates/mustache/v2-pub.json

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In reference to dustjs, Yes It's possible. I recommended you:

1. Read this tutorial: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial
2. Use linkedin version of dustjs: http://linkedin.github.com/dustjs
3. Use linkedin helpers: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers
4. Build your own helpers. It's easy.

Good luck!

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggested links.  Regrettably, i had to bail on dust.js for now.  I just couldn't make sense of the documentation; though i'm sure it would serve my purpose.  The good news is i've found that i can solve my problem by using handlebars.js, which plays well with mustache.js.  I'm using the helper functions in the handlebars.js framework to create the logic i needed (even though they're logic-less templates).  Here's a handlebars.js link i recommend: http://javascriptissexy.com/handlebars-js-tutorial-learn-everything-about-handlebars-js-javascript-templating/